# Disable parsing on number keyboard in iPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, jquery-mobile, keyboard

I need a keyboard which has both numbers and the - sign, since input="tel" is lacking it I figured I would use input="number" instead, however whenever I am done with the input it parses the number into another format, for instance: "19880522-3243" becomes "19 880 522".

Does anyone know either how I can get a numeric keyboard with "-" or disable the parsing that occurs with input="number"?

Comment: Does your input have a `pattern` attribute? Did you try adding `pattern="[0-9]*"` to the markup of the input?

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the jQuery Mobile [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/textinputs/). To quote the site:

> In jQuery Mobile, you can use existing and new HTML5 input types such
>   as password, email, tel, number, and more. Some type values are
>   rendered differently across browsers. For example, Chrome renders the
>   range input as a slider. jQuery Mobile standardizes the appearance of
>   range and search by dynamically changing their type to text. You can
>   configure which input types are degraded to text with the page
>   plugin's options.
>
> One major advantage of using these more specific input types if that
>   on mobile devices, specialized keyboards that speed data entry are
>   offered in place of the standard text keyboard. Try the following
>   inputs on a mobile device to see which display custom keyboards on
>   various platforms.

While not explicitly stated within the documentation, checking the source of the examples shows that input types can be defined by using the `type=""` attribute. Give this a whirl:

`<input type="tel" name="tel" id="tel" value="" />`